# Can an Android app discover the "service tag" of a Dell Android device?

Tags: android

I want to get service tag of a dell device using java or linux cmd's. Most manufacturers will support only serial number but dell devices also support service tags.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this: rather obviously if the poster simply wanted to know the service tag of a given device, they would look under the battery or whatever.  Rather, the question "using java or linux cmd's" indicates that the desire is to discover this dell-unique information **from within a program being developed** to run on the device (there is no facility to run java commands other than by developing an "app")

Comment: @ChrisStratton The dell tag was recently removed from all questions, see [the related meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225768/burninate-the-dell-tag).